# Find and select next string in textarea

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a find and replace functionality for a textarea in a javascript app.

I've got this pretty much working, but for an incredibly weird bug that I've no idea how to fix.

Essentially, 50% of the time this code works as expected. Every time I run the function, it selects the next instance of my string. However, the other 50% it just re-selects the same bit of text over and over.

This inconsistency is most confusing. I can relaunch the app and it works different each time. Here's my code. I'm guessing this might be performance related? Any ideas?

```
function selectNext() {
    // collect variables
    var findBox = document.getElementById('findBox');
    var editable = document.getElementById('editable');
    var txt = editable.innerText;
    var strSearchTerm = findBox.value;

    // find next index of searchterm, starting from current cursor position
    var cursorPos = editable.selectionEnd;
    var termPos = txt.indexOf(strSearchTerm, cursorPos);

    // if found, select it
    if (termPos != -1) {
        editable.setSelectionRange(termPos, termPos + strSearchTerm.length)
    } else {
        // not found from cursor pos, so start from beginning
        termPos = txt.indexOf(strSearchTerm);
        if (termPos != -1) {
            editable.setSelectionRange(termPos, termPos + strSearchTerm.length)
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle/demo?